# Thrift Serialization and Deserialization in Kafka Streaming

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, thrift

I am using thrift just to do serialization and deserialization for performance improvement while streaming byte data from kafka

When I deserialize, I keep getting this error:

> org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Unrecognized type 123

My Code

```
public void streamMessageByte() {   
    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<Integer, byte[]> stream = builder.stream(kafka_topic);
    deserializer = new TDeserializer();
    serializer = new TSerializer();
    //Thrift class pojo object is 'deser' which matches byte array data format
    stream.map((k,v){

        try{
            deserializer.deserialize(deser, v);
        }

        catch(TException e){

        }
    null;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem, when I was using different protocols to serialize and deserialize.

The serializer was usind `ObjectMapper` and the deserializer was using `TDeserializer` with `TBinaryProtocol`. Example:

```
@Test
public void testSerDe() throws TException, JsonProcessingException {
   final Person person = new Person("Thomas", Byte.valueOf("23"));
   JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   byte[] serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(person).getBytes();
   TDeserializer deserializer = new TDeserializer(TBinaryProtocol::new);
   Person desPerson = new Person();
   deserializer.deserialize(desPerson, serialized);
   assertEquals(person, desPerson);
}
```

That would throw `org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Unrecognized type 123`

It should work if you serialize and deserialize the same way.
Here is an example:

```
@Test
public void testSerDe() throws TException {
   // Given
   final Person person = new Person("Thomas", Byte.valueOf("23"));
   TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer(TBinaryProtocol::new);
   // When
   byte[] serializedPerson = serializer.serialize(person);
   // Then
   TDeserializer deserializer = new TDeserializer(TBinaryProtocol::new);
   GraphEvent dePerson = new Person();
   deserializer.deserialize(dePerson, serializedPerson);
   assertEquals(person, dePerson);
}
```

Comment: Jackson has binary serializers as well. And Thrift should be able to handle Java objects as-is. In the first example, you are using Thrift to serialize a UTF-8 JSON string. This will take more space over the wire than native Thrift serialization.